# Trying to see a slight problem in a proof a existence of square roots

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

[image]

I am having difficulties seeing the circled expression. I understand since $\dfrac{2 r }{\delta/2} $ is a real number, then we can always find and integer $m > 0$ so that $\dfrac{2 r }{\delta/2} < m$. Now notice that

$$ \dfrac{ 1}{\delta/2} < \dfrac{m}{2r} $$

but it is not guarantee that $\dfrac{m}{2r} < m < m^2$ unless $r>1$ but this may not be true. Also, isnt $m \geq 0$? Why would $m^2 > m$. This fails if $m=0$. Can someone clarify this to me? thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what can be assumed, but by the Archimedian property, you can find $n \geq 1$ such that $2r/(\delta/2) < n$, and by the same property, you can find $\ell \geq 1$ such that $1/(\delta/2) < \ell$. Set $m := n+\ell$. Then $m \geq 2$ has your desired properties, right?